# How to insert date of birth using three select boxes?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

i want to insert date of birth in my table using three select boxes, the first one is DD, second one is MM and the last one is YYYY.

Here is the code of my html.

```
<tr>
<td>Date of birth</td>
<td>
<select style="width:50px;" name="dob">
<option>DD</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select style="width:60px;" name="dob">
<option>MM</option>
<option value="january">January</option>
<option value="february">February</option>
<option value="march">March</option>
<option value="april">April</option>
<option value="may">May</option>
<option value="june">June</option>
<option value="july">July</option>
<option value="august">August</option>
<option value="september">September</option>
<option value="october">October</option>
<option value="november">November</option>
<option value="december">December</option>
</select>

<select style="width:65px;" name="dob">
<option>YYYY</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

And this is the code of my jsp page.

```
String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
String queryString = "INSERT INTO user(id, dob,) VALUES (null, ?)";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
ps.setString(1, dob);
```

After insertion, in my table in dob field only the DD part is inserted, the rest MM and YYYY is not inserted.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.getParameter("dob")` will give you only one value as you have given *same name* for all three dropdown fields you will get the first one only which is date.

You should use different names for different select fields and than use get paramater for all of them and then *concat* three values to create date.